# WARN: Failed to load URLs from https://localhost:8080/realms/Knolx/.well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: java, scala, jwt, keycloak, verify

I am trying to verify the JWT token using KeyCloak but I see the following error when I run the code below.
Is this the right way or is there any other way to install the oidc client in keycloak to verify the jwt token?
Can anyone help with this?

This is the code that I am trying to execute. It is using keycloak to verify the jwt token. i have created a client and a user in keycloak.

**Code**

```
  val adapterConfig = new AdapterConfig
  adapterConfig.setRealm("Knolx")
  adapterConfig.setResource("client-01")
  adapterConfig.setAuthServerUrl("https://localhost:8080/")
  adapterConfig.setSslRequired("external")
  adapterConfig.setVerifyTokenAudience(true)
  val credentialMap:Map[String,AnyRef] = Map("secret"->"secret")
  adapterConfig.setCredentials(credentialMap.asJava)
  adapterConfig.setUseResourceRoleMappings(true)
  adapterConfig.setConfidentialPort(0)
  val depl = KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(adapterConfig)
  val tokenToVerify = "token"

  try{
    val tok = AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(tokenToVerify, depl);
    println(tok.getPreferredUsername)
    println(tok.getSubject)
  }
  catch{
    case e: VerificationException => println(e)

  }
```

**Error**

```
org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment resolveUrls
WARN: Failed to load URLs from https://localhost:8080/realms/Knolx/.well-known/openid-configuration
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:451)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:175)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1500)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1415)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:421)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:570)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:554)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.SniSSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SniSSLSocketFactory.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:605)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:440)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getOidcConfiguration(KeycloakDeployment.java:230)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.resolveUrls(KeycloakDeployment.java:182)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment.getRealmInfoUrl(KeycloakDeployment.java:246)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.createVerifier(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:107)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(AdapterTokenVerifier.java:47)
    at Playground$.delayedEndpoint$Playground$1(Playground.scala:55)
    at Playground$delayedInit$body.apply(Playground.scala:11)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:563)
    at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:561)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:926)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at Playground$.main(Playground.scala:11)
    at Playground.main(Playground.scala)

org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment resolveUrls
WARN: Failed to load URLs from https://localhost:8080/realms/Knolx/.well-known/openid-configuration
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:451)
```

Comment: You're using https for your localhost connection, and you're getting an invalid ssl error. try http://localhost/...

Comment: how to set it using the code?

Comment: I changed the connection to http. Now it shows the following error-

INFO: Loaded URLs from http://localhost:8080/realms/Knolx/.well-known/openid-configuration
org.keycloak.common.VerificationException: Expected audience not available in the token

Comment: that’s not an error, it’s just an INFO log. Everything is ok

Comment: But I don't see the required output which is the username. It says audience is not availabe

Comment: That’s another issue, your probably using the wrong token. Google this: expected audience not available in token. Also, staxkoverflow just converted my text to a link, put http before localhost :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244210/discussion-between-aman-verma-and-aminmal).